# Telerik RadMaskedNumericInput - displaying 0's when loaded

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, telerik

So the basic problem is I am using a Telerik control the RadMaskedNumericInput in a wpf form. The behavior is exactly as I need however when the form loads its shows 0.000 in the field and I need it blank... Can anyone see where I went wrong with this.

starting value = null
mask = #5.3

```
<telerik:RadMaskedNumericInput  Value="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay}" 
    AutoFillNumberGroupSeparators="False" 
    SelectionOnFocus="SelectAll" 
    UpdateValueEvent="PropertyChanged" 
    Mask="{Binding Mask}" Placeholder=" " 
    TextMode="PlainText" IsClearButtonVisible="False" 
    FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0,5,5,0" DockPanel.Dock="Left"    
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" AutoFillZeros="False" Text="" />
```

Comment: If you are binding to a nullable int, then it will default to 0. See here for more info: http://www.telerik.com/forums/urgent-when-null-showing.

Comment: @momar I found that shortly after posting, I had to update the code behind to show a nullable double